# Subtle change of a background-image

Tags: jquery, css

I have been trying to find an answer via google for a while now but to no avail.

I've come across an interesting feature on site: http://dicksonfong.com/

The feature involves the background image, which appears to change from the bottom as a section passes up the screen. I can't describe it any better which is probably why I'm geting no hits on Google.

Can anyone identify what this trick is called and where I can find the source code to implement something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Simon

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax

Comment: find linked site quite laggy. Users like nice design but dislike lagging site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called `Parallax` effect scrolling. It looks very creative in terms of UI and involves a lot of things for it to work. If you want to start off with, Here is an [Ideal example for a start](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice [JavaScript library called `skrollr`](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for making parallax scrolling websites.

It requires of You to only know **HTML and CSS**.

More [examples](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 2):

The above answers about Parallax are incorrect. Parallax does create some amazing looking websites. However, the one you linked to (http://dicksonfong.com/), doesn't use it. This is because Parallax happens when one has multiple levels moving at different speeds.

Imagine that the speed of your scrolling is 100%. If an image is moving with the entire page, it's moving at 100%. If it's not moving at all, it's moving at 0%. If it's moving half speed, 50%. Parallax incorporates multiple moving speeds. Dickson's site simply has content, moving at 100%, and backgrounds, moving at either 100% or 0%. Since 0% means unmoving, there is only one speed at which moving items are moving.

That said, it's still a cool website, and because it is more simple, it's easier to create, requiring zero javascript (or HTML5). He simply uses fixed backgrounds, and absolute positioning. His first and third rows have fixed backgrounds. This allows for them to remain in place.

Example Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="home" class="page">

    <div class="content">

        <h1>First Page</h1>

        Content here!

    </div>

</div>

<div class="divider">

    <div class="content">Divider</div>

</div>

<div id="about" class="page">

    <div class="content">

        <h1>First Page</h1>

        Content here.

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:80px; 
    font-family:Calibri; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 4px white;
}

.page {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 800px;
}

.divider {  
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    position: relative; 
}

.page .content {
    height: 450px; 
    top: 100px; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.divider .content { 
    padding-top:50px; 
    height: 250px; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#home { 
    background: url(background_home.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover;  
}
#about { 
    background: url(background_about.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0 / cover;
}
```

Working Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/6Hck4/1/